# Loopback is not loading css files

Tags: javascript, html, express, loopbackjs

I have the follow code:

```
app.middleware('files', '/lib', loopback.static(path.normalize(__dirname + '/lib')));
```

But I am getting this error on cosole:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Any idea why? The location of my css files is correct and the file is there.

Thanks

I am trying to integrate Raneto with Loopback, if someone can give me a hand I would apretiate it.

Here my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{config.locale}}">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>{{#meta.title}}{{meta.title}} - {{/meta.title}}{{config.site_title}}</title>
  {{#meta.description}}<meta name="description" content="{{meta.description}}">{{/meta.description}}
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="shortcut icon", href="http://buildmetric.com/favicon.ico?v=2">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{config.base_url}}/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{config.base_url}}/lib/highlightjs/styles/solarized_light.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{config.base_url}}/styles/raneto.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{config.base_url}}/styles/ghostdown.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{config.base_url}}/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{config.base_url}}/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/animate.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{config.base_url}}/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/hover.css" />

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{config.base_url}}/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/style.css" />
  {{{config.analytics}}}

</head>
<body class="{{body_class}}">
```

Full path:

```
http://localhost:5000/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Comment: any suggestion noone?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML you used to include the CSS file?

Comment: Can you show us what the full path the server is trying to get? Because obviously, the location of the file it's looking for, isn't correct.

Comment: There you have guys.

Comment: There you have my code @Lee

Comment: @RaymondCamden You can see my code now.

Comment: And if you take that full path, and put that into a browser, does the contents of the stylesheet show up?

Comment: the idea is to integrate both technologies.